# SharePoint 2013 Search Results Trim Duplicates

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search-results, sharepoint-on-prem

I have added a search results webpart which returns only a subset of documents. I have around 15 documents but search is only returning 7. I noticed the missing document have similar content with few modifications.

I came across this article which mentions about the Trim Duplicates attribute. Does anyone know if this issue is fixed in the Latest service packs. I have April 2015 CU.

http://blogs.perficient.com/microsoft/2013/04/sharepoint-2013-search-not-display-all-results/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just open the web part and Edit the Query. On the Settings tab there is an option to disable duplicate trimming. No need to export the web part.

[image: Remove Duplicates Screenshot]

Comment: Added screenshot to answer

Answer (score 1):

Hopefull this helps you,

This was answered on another site, this is what we did as well and it worked

--

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/3982c56e-7c22-4f25-bffa-43d313c64d52/how-disable-trimduplicates-in-the-search-result-webpart-under-sharepoint-2013?forum=sharepointsearch

> This was driving me insane for days as well, and I finally found a
>   solution. What I did was:
>
> Add a standard search result webpart to a page Export the webpart and
>   save it on disk Edit the *.webpart file that was exported in notepad
>   Look for the text: "TrimDuplicates":true Change it to:
>   "TrimDuplicates":false Save the file and and import it as a new
>   webpart

Sorry, I cant answer the part about the service pack updating this, I dont think it will be fixed as this is probably by design...

Comment: I have already done that using the export option... I also found another option in Search webpart settings as mentioned in the link... I'll try that...