# How to remove duplicates from SharePoint Enterprise Search results?

Tags: enterprise-search, sharepoint-search

I am facing an issue in SharePoint Search. I have connected External content type in SharePoint site collection and my source has single entity of particular item but in SharePoint search I am getting duplicate records for the single item. I don't why it is coming. 
I tried this `TrimDuplicates=true` but also getting duplicate results.

Help me to solve this issue. SharePoint Search service has an issue but how to solve that issue ?

Answer (score 2):

[SharePoint 2013 Search Results Trim Duplicates](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/150839/sharepoint-2013-search-results-trim-duplicates)

Just open the web part and Edit the Query. On the Settings tab there is an option to disable duplicate trimming. No need to export the web part.
[image]

Try this Also

Disable view duplicates search functionality. To fix this, just disable the view duplicates search functionality.

1. Execute a search in order to get to the search results page (by default results.aspx)
2. Choose Site Actions -> Edit Page.
3. Choose Modify Shared Web Part on the Search Core Results Web Part.
4. Uncheck the checkbox “Remove Duplicate Results”.
5. Choose OK and Publish the page.

Comment: I have done all of this thing but still getting duplicates.